nginx fails to start for readonlyRootfilesystem
i am trying to configure nginx for a readonlyRootfilesystem.
i am running nginx inside docker as
docker run --read-only -v /tmp -p 8000:8000 -i -t <image> /bin/bash

but by default nginx creates some directories at location /var/lib/nginx , /var/log/nginx , /etc/nginx

i am looking for nginx to create these directories at a different location /tmp other than /var/lib , as /tmp is mounted as a different volume in the setup which i have currently where the filesystem is set to be readonly  and when the filesystem is set to be readonly nginx fails with the error

could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log"
failed (30: Read-only file system)

here is
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user  www-data;
worker_processes  auto;

pid        /tmp/nginx/nginx.pid;

error_log   /tmp/log/nginx/error.log warn;

include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;



events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';


    access_log  /tmp/log/nginx/access.log  main;


    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    # Temporary directories for "readonlyfilesystem"
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/log/nginx/nginx-client-body;
    proxy_temp_path       /tmp/log/nginx/nginx-proxy;
    fastcgi_temp_path     /tmp/log/nginx/nginx-fastcgi;
    uwsgi_temp_path       /tmp/log/nginx/nginx-uwsgi;
    scgi_temp_path        /tmp/log/nginx/nginx-scgi;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}

Here is the process info
ps -ef | grep nginx
root@929b5a6a057e:/app# ps -ef | grep nginx
root         9     1  0 05:30 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon off;
www-data    11     9  0 05:30 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    12     9  0 05:30 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    13     9  0 05:30 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    14     9  0 05:30 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    15     9  0 05:30 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    16     9  0 05:30 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    17     9  0 05:30 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process

Here is my sites conf file

log location

Even though i have changed the log location in nginx.conf but still nginx -v shows as /var/log/nginx

How can i configure nginx to run with a readonlyfilesystem ?

Check which user is running Nginx. By default, you can find this in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file, specifically by looking for the user directive (http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user). After that, make sure that user has permission to read/write the paths you need.
The error you mentioned (Could not open error log file: open() '/var/log/nginx/error.log' failed (30: Read-only file system)) might be happening because, since Nginx is unable to write to the specified paths, it tries to log the error to its default path (/var/log/nginx/error.log). It’s possible that with the changes you're making, this path no longer exists.

The path exists , i have updated question with more details , kindly check

Check the user running the Nginx service:
ps -ef | grep nginx

Added above , master process runs as root while the worker processes is run by www-data

Ok, perfect. Does the path "/tmp/log/nginx" exist on the machine? What permissions does it have?

i have updated the nginx.conf

"nginx -v" shows the build information, that's why you see the default log path, if you want to see your entire configuration then run "nginx -T" (the "t" is capitalized). But anyway, back to the problem, what is the reason for you to want to read Nginx configuration and save its logs in non-standard paths?

As mentioned above as well , as part of security the rootfilesystem should be readonly , so had to move to non standard locations

Alright, I understand. I see that you changed the screenshots you had previously posted, and now I notice that you've also changed the ownership of the files in your log directory. As far as I know, the user you’re using for Nginx is 'www-data', but in the current screenshot, you’re showing that those files belong to the 'root' user, so they won’t be able to be modified by Nginx. You can fix this by navigating to the /var/log/nginx directory:
cd /var/log/nginx
sudo chown www-data:www-data * -R

Make sure you are in the correct directory before running the chown command.

If you want to change the path to the nginx.conf file, try modifying the value of CONFIGFILE in /etc/init.d/nginx to ${CONFFILE:-/your-path/nginx.conf}.
Save the change, refresh the service configuration with sudo systemctl daemon-reload, and apply it with sudo systemctl reload nginx.

I think nginx is already pointing to the default location where the nginx conf,  is , PID=$(cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep -Ev '^\s*#' | awk 'BEGIN { RS="[;{}]" } { if ($1 == "pid") print $2 }' | head -n1) , but yet the nginx looks for logs at /var/logs/nginx , how can i point it to the location i mentioned in the conf file

Some of the logs are created by the master process of nginx and some are made under user , not very sure how it works in the background

Check if the /tmp directory is mounted as read-only with:
mount | grep /tmp
Another option you have is to mount a RAM drive (tmpfs): sudo mkdir -p /mnt/nginx-logs
Edit the file /etc/fstab and add: tmpfs   /mnt/nginx-logs   tmpfs   defaults,size=100M   0  0
Mount the drive: sudo mount /mnt/nginx-logs
And use /mnt/nginx-logs instead of /tmp/log/nginx.
Make sure to set the permissions:
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /mnt/nginx-logs and sudo chmod -R 755 /mnt/nginx-logs

Added more details above , and /tmp is already mounted as a docker volume
